# How to sort an array in D3 without affecting the assigned color order

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

I've assigned the colors to my pie chart and it's working great - they follow the suit from blue to red perfectly. I wanted to order the slices according to their order, too, so I made the following substitution.

```
var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  //.sort(null)
  .sort(d3.ascending)
  .value(function (d) { return d["val"]; });
```

The sizes are now in the desired order but the colors follow the old order and look wrong. I want the colors to be red for the biggest slice and blue for the smallest one.

Please view the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2x7ncns/9/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly define the range like below:

```
var colors = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([d3.min(data), d3.max(data)])
    .range(["blue", "red"]);
```

Here the min in the array will correspond to blue.
Here the max in the array will correspond to red.

Set the color in the path as per the data, and not as per its **index** like this:

```
grx.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function (d, i) {  return colors(d.data);});
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lyb9hkd/1/)